# Pausing tar|split while disk is full

Tags: linux, backup, download, disk-space, archiving

I'd like to get a backup of some files from a server. The basic idea is to create an archive using `tar`, saving it to disk, and downloading it. The problem is the lack of remaining disk space (or RAM for a tmpfs), forcing me to split the archive and download it in chunks.

Is there an easy way (e.g. by adding another command between the pipe from `tar` to `split`) to make `split` pause, when the disk is too full for the next piece, and continue when the disk is free again? (By default, split just exits with an error message when writing failed due to a full disk.)

Alternatives that I'd like to avoid:

- Piping the tar via SSH to save it directly on the destination -- the connection might break when the download runs too long, and the downloading client is running Windows.
- Using [dsplit](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dsplit/) (or sth similar to create multiple tar archives) -- I expect that this will prevent me from concatenating the archives after downloading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most below there is *quick and dirty* `sh` script designed to work as a filter (between `tar` and `split` in your case). It was built in Ubuntu and may need some adjustments for other systems (e.g. I'm not sure if `column -t | cut -d " " -f 7` is the right way to parse `df` regardless of OS). It requires `/proc`.

Save it as `ensuredf` where your `$PATH` points to, make executable (`chmod -x ensuredf`) and use like this:

```
… | ensuredf path requirement | …
```

where

- `path` is the directory you want to monitor;
- `requirement` is the desired free space (`df -B` must understand this);

Example:

```
… | ensuredf /mnt/foo/data/ 2G | …
```

The idea is to let background `cat` pass data from `stdin` (of the script) to `stdout` but pause it immediately. Then invoke `df` for a given `path`, parse its output and check if there's more space than `requirement`. If so, `cat` is resumed, otherwise it is paused. This loops with a hardcoded interval of 1 second as long as `/proc` entry for this `cat` exists.

Other notes:

- some filesystems (especially BTRFS) make `df` output not as exact as you'd like;
- if your `tar` is very fast and your required space is very low, the interval of 1 second may be too long;
- but even if the interval were zero, when the free space gets below the `requirement` there will be some delay before `cat` is paused;
- if for some reason the foreground script gets delayed and the background `cat` works well, the disk may get full anyway.

This means you should set your `requirement` with proper safety margin. Use this code as an example and adjust to your needs. I managed to write a safer script that keeps invoking foreground `dd` to pass a chunk of data *if and only if* there's enough disk space, but these multiple `dd` processes were a lot slower than a single `cat`.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -eq 2 ] || { printf '%s\n' "usage: $0 path requirement" >&2 ; exit 1;}

pth="$1"
rqrmnt="$2"
intrvl=1

</proc/$$/fd/0 cat >/proc/$$/fd/1 &
kill -s STOP $!

while [ -d /proc/$! ] ; do
  if [ $(df -P -B "$rqrmnt" "$pth" | tail -n 1 | column -t | cut -d " " -f 7) -ge 2 ]
  then kill -s CONT $!
  else kill -s STOP $!
  fi
  sleep "$intrvl"
done
```

Comment: Thanks -- I hoped for a ready-to-use packaged tool, but this will work for now. Looks as if I have to write something counting and throttling/pausing the transferred data myself on the long term, I fear some timing issues. Or I might have buy some new disks... ;)